# jQuery Mobile Drop Down Menu Causing Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, mobile

I have a drop down menu on this development Wordpress site: http://zap2dev.redzephyr.biz/ the mobile menu appears to be working fine however upon pressing the mobile menu icon the menu displays and promptly the page begins reloading. Obviously on reload the mobile menu is collapsed again so begins the vicious cycle.

Any ideas what could be causing the page to reload?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<a class="navicon mtoggle" href="">` to `<div class="navicon mtoggle">`
then update your css

```
nav#mobile .navicon{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I know this is an old topic but I am having the same issue and I can't find where I'm supposed to update `<a class="navicon mtoggle" href="">`? What file do I find this in? Similarly, is the CSS section to update in `style.php` or is it in a different file? Thanks very much if you can please help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

Try making your toggle not a link and instead a div. Otherwise with javascript assign on click or touch to prevent.default which would cause the browser from trying to open the link which doesn't have an assigned href and reloads the page.